# Find the difference between a table in QA and Production environment(Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find the difference between a table in QA and Production environment(Oracle), for which I have created a DB link and using this query.

```
Select column1, column2, column3 from table1--This is QA table
minus
(Select column1, column2, column3 from table1@prod)--This is Production table
```

column1, column2, column3 make a unique record,  the table also has columns "created date" and "created by"(may not be same for a given record in production and QA), which I want to display for records that are there in QA but not in Production. Can this be done without using a Join?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `not exists` clause?

```
select * 
from table1 q 
where not exists (
                     select 1
                     from table1@prod p
                     where p.column1 = q.column1
                     and p.column2 = q.column2
                     and p.column3 = q.column3
                 )
```